# Should I replace the “can’t” with “won’t be able to”?

Tags: grammar

Should I replace the “can’t” with “won’t be able to” in the following sentences?

Example 1

A: Do you know where to buy some apples?

B: Why?

A: They have some of the best apples in the world here, and we are leaving very early in the morning tomorrow. If I don’t buy some tonight, I **can’t** make some delicious apple juice tomorrow.

Example 2

A: Will you come to my party?

B: I am not sure. I might have to work overtime.

A: Come on! If you don’t come, I **can’t** introduce you to my family tomorrow.

Comment: _Won't be able to_ is the logical tense to use, but _can't_ would be acceptable in informal speech.

Comment: How about: If it rains tonight, I **can’t** play basketball in the park.

Comment: Well, yes, the same applies, and to any similar sentence.

Comment: So it seems “won’t be able to” fits better than “can’t” in all sentences that refer to future.

Comment: You can use the simple present to talk about the future for scheduled events/plans/timetables.  For example: The train arrives at six p.m. Dinner is at seven p.m. The shop closes at eight tonight.  I can't pick you up at nine tonight. Can I pick you up at ten p.m. instead? etc.  This is perfectly acceptable, and often preferred to using the future, especially in speech.  Sometimes "I won't/will be able to" can sound quite formal, even unnatural/stilted in a conversation.

Comment: I think maybe it’s because I use a conditional (if…..) for example: If it rains, we won’t be able to go out tonight. But it seems can is more interchangeable with will be able to:”if it stops raining, we can play basketball in the park tonight” sounds fine